# Confusion à l'oral autour "je connais plus"

Tags: sens, expressions, usage, oral

Quand j'entend  je ne connais plus de personne ici, je comprends qu'il ne connais pas d'autres personne, mais quand j'entends " je connais plus de personne " (supprimé le pronom ne  ce qui est très connait en oral) , est ce qu'elle reste la même phrase où bien elle signifié qu''il connait d'autres personne ? Merci d'avance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tout dépend de la prononciation de "plus" : s'il est prononcé sans le s : comme "plu", alors cela signifie "je ne connais plus de personne". Si il est prononcé avec le s : "pluce", alors cela veut dire "je connais d'autres personnes".

On peut parfois trouver "pluce" prononcé "plu", mais c'est peu commun et souvent humoristique.

Attention toutefois "personne" en tant que nom est dénombrable. Ici on dira plutôt "Je ne connais plus personne" qui devient "je connais plus ("plu") personne. Et "je connais plus ("pluce") de personnes" ou plus courant : "je connais plus ("pluce") de monde".

La confusion citée ici fonctionne mieux avec "je veux plus de café".

Comment: normalement *je veux plus de café* ne devrait pas poser de problème, puisque pour dire "plu" il faut écrire *je **ne** veux plus de café*, mais c'est vrai qu'on a de plus en plus tendance à ne pas mettre *ne*